# Repeating and Overlapping UITableView cells in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

The UITableView cells are repeating on scroll and overlapping each other.
How can i fix this issue

here is my code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 11;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIButton *buyBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImageView *img;
    UILabel *lbl;
    UIImageView *backImage;
    UILabel *textLabel;
    UILabel *detailTextLabel;

    NSInteger val = [indexPath row] * 3;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        backImage =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 4, 316, 62)];
        [buyBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(257, 35, 57, 24)];
        img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(257, 10, 57, 24)];

        lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 57, 24)];
        textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 230, 25)];
        detailTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 25, 230, 30)];

        backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shop-bg.png"];
        [buyBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buy_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"price_button.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
        backImage =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 4, 316, 62)];
        [buyBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(257, 35, 57, 24)];
        img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(257, 10, 57, 24)];

        lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 57, 24)];
        textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 230, 25)];
        detailTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 25, 230, 30)];

        backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shop-bg.png"];
        [buyBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buy_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"price_button.png"]];
    }



    lbl.center = img.center;
    lbl.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl.text = [self.original_List objectAtIndex:val+2];
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:14];
    textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textLabel.text = [self.original_List objectAtIndex:val];

    detailTextLabel.text = [self.original_List objectAtIndex:val+1];
    detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:10];
    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

    [buyBtn setTag:[indexPath row]];
    [buyBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buyBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];



    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"myIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"%d" , [[cell subviews] count]);
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    }
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:backImage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:detailTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:buyBtn];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIButton *buyBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImageView *img;
    UILabel *lbl;
    UIImageView *backImage;
    UILabel *textLabel;
    UILabel *detailTextLabel;

    NSInteger val = [indexPath row] * 3;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        backImage =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 4, 316, 62)];
        [buyBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(257, 35, 57, 24)];
        img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(257, 10, 57, 24)];

        lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 57, 24)];
        textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 230, 25)];
        detailTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 25, 230, 30)];

        backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shop-bg.png"];
        [buyBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buy_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"price_button.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
        backImage =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 4, 316, 62)];
        [buyBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(257, 35, 57, 24)];
        img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(257, 10, 57, 24)];

        lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 57, 24)];
        textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 230, 25)];
        detailTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 25, 230, 30)];

        backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shop-bg.png"];
        [buyBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buy_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"price_button.png"]];
    }



    lbl.center = img.center;
    lbl.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl.text = [self.original_List objectAtIndex:val+2];
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:14];
    textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textLabel.text = [self.original_List objectAtIndex:val];

    detailTextLabel.text = [self.original_List objectAtIndex:val+1];
    detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:10];
    textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

    [buyBtn setTag:[indexPath row]];
    [buyBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buyBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];



    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"myIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"%d" , [[cell subviews] count]);
    //if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    }
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:backImage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:detailTextLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:buyBtn];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check height for cell in 
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

It should be greater then max height used in your code may be 65

Answer (score 0):

Don't use reuseIdentifier and set to nil.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
```

This code makes sure that when you are scrolling in a UITableView, the cell gets reused to save on memory. Since you are using the same identifier for all cells, it will just reuse a cell that already has a 'backImage', 'detailTextLabel' and so forth, and add the new view components on top of the already existing ones.

You could fix this by using a code similar to this:

```
static NSString *myIdentifier = @"myIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    // Create backImage, detailTextLabel, etc. here
    ...

    // Give view components tags
    backImage.tag = 1;
    detailTextLabel.tag = 2;
    ...
}

UIImageView* retrievedBackImage = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
UILabel* retrievedDetailTextLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
...
// Initialise values
retrievedBackImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
retrievedDetailTextLabel.text = @"something";
...
```

Hope this was helpful.

Nicolas